# HTA writing to a <span> from a text file

Tags: powershell, hta

I am trying to write data from a text file to a  in an HTA.

I'm running a powershell script inside of the HTA, using VBscript for the input buttons

```
Get-TSSession -computername ismeta | where { $_.username -eq 'amis5235'} | format-table windowstationname,username,state,sessionid | out-file C:\windows\temp\PSTerminalServices.txt
```

I'm going to be using a for each loop for about 60 servers

Then I was hoping to write the output to a  within the HTA, kind of like a streamer in VB or stacking a string the VBscript, something like:

```
strHTML = strHTML & "Running Process = " & objProcess.Name & " PID = " & objProcess.ProcessID & " Description = " & objProcess.Description & "<br>"
```

but it seems there should be a simpler way to do this.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. You are not able to generate a <span></span> line from poweshell ? Why are you using HTA and not Windows Forms for you UIs in PowerShell ?

Comment: Mostly I was looking for an alternative GUI to full on VB, which can be more pain than it's worth, I've played around with some tutorial HTA's for VBScript and liked the flexibility and easy learning curve they offered, even Ed Wilson MS's powershell posterboy recommends using them for powershell scripts http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2009/08/31/hey-scripting-guy-can-i-create-a-gui-for-a-windows-powershell-script.aspx , if there is a better way feel free to point me in that direction

Answer (score 1):

I think this minimal HTA will solve your problem. It runs a command line and reads the output stream, one line every 1/10 second, then pushes the results into a textarea. You may want to alter your Powershell script to return the process details to STDOUT, but it will probably work.

```
<script language="Javascript">
var E, LineWriteTimerID
function execWithStatus(cmdLine){//Can't run minimized with Exec. Can't capture StdOut/StdErr with Run. 
    E = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell").Exec(cmdLine);
    LineWriteTimerID = window.setInterval("writeOutLine()",100);//pause for 100ms
    E.StdIn.Close();//must close input to complete a ps command    
}
function writeOutLine(){
    if(E.StdOut.AtEndOfStream) window.clearTimeout(LineWriteTimerID);
    if(!E.StdErr.AtEndOfStream) txtResults.value += "ERROR: " + E.StdErr.ReadAll() + "\n";
    if(!E.StdOut.AtEndOfStream) txtResults.value += E.StdOut.ReadLine() + "\n";
}
</script>
<textarea id=txtCmd style="width:90%" rows=1>
powershell.exe -noninteractive -command ls c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\</textarea> 
<button onclick="execWithStatus(txtCmd.value)">Run</button>
<br><textarea id=txtResults style="width:100%" rows=20></textarea>
```

Save this code as an .HTA file, change the contents of the txtCmd textarea to be your command line, and give it a try. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Ok Here is the way I use.

On the theorical point of view it consist in building an interface with Windows Forms and then put PowerSell code behind event.

On technical point of view two solutions :

1) Use visual studio free edition to build interface in C# and then a conversion tool to create the associate PowerShell source ([french article here](http://www.powershell-scripting.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=134&Itemid=71))

2) you can download freely (you just need to register) [Sapiens](http://www.sapien.com/) PrimalFormsCE.exe (Community Edition)

[image: PrimalFormsCE download]

This tool allow you create a form and then to generate Powershell associete code.

[image: PrimalFormsCE image]

You can also build forms from crash here is a peace of sample code :

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName system.Windows.Forms

# Create the form
$form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = "Test Saisie"
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(250,154)

# Create EntryFiel
$TB_Saisie = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$TB_Saisie.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(50,31)
$TB_Saisie.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,32)

# Create "Ok" Button
$PB_Ok = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$PB_Ok.Text = "Ok"
$PB_Ok.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(50,62)
$PB_Ok.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,32)
$PB_Ok.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK

# Create "Cancel" Button
$PB_Cancel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$PB_Cancel.Text = "Cancel"
$PB_Cancel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,62)
$PB_Cancel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,32)
$PB_Cancel.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
# Add controls to the form
$form.Controls.Add($PB_Ok)
$form.Controls.Add($PB_Cancel)
$form.Controls.Add($TB_Saisie)

# Message loop
$Res = $form.ShowDialog()
If ($Res -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
  Write-Host ("Accepted : {0}" -f $TB_Saisie.Text)
}
else
{
  Write-Host "Cancel"
}
```

Comment: looks remarkably like VB6, I'll check it out thanks, though I still think it's possible to do what I'm asking, at least according to MS it is, just no good example out there